# Table column to expand to fill page without wrapping

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table that has a bunch of columns, and most of them will hold short enough data that I'm not worried about an overflow. However, there is one column that could have sentence-length data. I don't want to allow this to overflow on multiple lines, so I've added this to my css (the table is in a `.gridTable` class):

```
.gridTable td:nth-last-child(2) {
     max-width: 100px;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     white-space: nowrap;
}
```

And this is working perfectly. Now, however, I want to allow that column to expand as long as the table does not become wider than the width of the page. I have my general table style defined here:

```
.gridTable{
     border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
     border-collapse: collapse;
     border-spacing: 0; 
     float:left;
     table-layout: fixed;
     max-width: 100%;           
}
```

So, as you can see, the table should be able to expand to fill the width of the page. There is one other column that is of varying length--up to about 200px at the max. I don't want this column to ever have to overflow onto another line. Is there a way I can specify my second-to-last column to have a max-width of the remaining width of the page, instead of a fixed number like 100px?

EDIT:

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="gridTable">
  <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" >
</asp:GridView></div>
```

I actually define the table in the code behind:

```
 GridView1.DataSource = dt;
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

That's all the code that I think is relevant, but if someone thinks I'm missing anything, let me know!

Comment: You need to post the HTML code, and make a live demo will be helpful.

Comment: You could use view-port units on that `td`, like `max-width: 70vw`. This will let the `td` be 70% of the view-port width at max.